# Finish proof with false hypothesis in Coq

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

So I have a false hypothesis in a subgoal. It's an equality between different constructors. How do I finish the subgoal?

```
H: List.Not_Empty Bit.Bit Bit.Zero (List.Empty Bit.Bit) = List.Empty Bit.Bit
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't look like the Coq List I'm used to from the standard library, so it will be hard to help you without knowing the definitions of List.Not_Empty and List.Empty. If I guess correctly that `List.Empty` stands for `nil` and `List.Not_empty` stands for `cons`, then it's just a matter of showing that the two constructors are not equal. You can for instance do:

```
congruence.
```

or simply:

```
inversion H.
```

However, if it's something more involved, these two might fail. So you'd want to either:

```
SearchAbout List.Not_Empty.
```

to see if lemmas exist about it, or to:

```
unfold List.Not_Empty, List.Empty in H.
```

to unfold definitions and work out the details (possibly saving this subproof as a lemma if it does not exist, as it seems useful).

Comment: `inversion H` did the trick. `Empty` and `Not_Empty` are just the constructors of my `List`.